# React triggering components from another component

Tags: reactjs, triggers, rxjs, react-hooks, state

#### Scenario

I want to know how to pass triggers between components without using callbacks from props.

This my tree diagram

```
- Dashboard
 - Progress
 - MyJobs
  - JobRecord
    - DateRecords
    - DateForm 
  - JobRecord
    - DateRecords
    - DateForm 
  - JobRecord
    - DateRecords
    - DateForm
```

When the DateForm is submitted I want there to be a trigger sent to the Progress component, it should then fetch some data, do some math and display the result. What is the best way to do that.

#### Components

**DateForm**

```
const DateForm = () => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null
  })

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // add data to database (ignore this)
    // do something here to send to the Progress component
  }

  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="date" value={values.startDate} />
      <input type="date" value={values.endDate} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

**Progress**

```
const Progress = () => {

  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch some data from the database when the dateform is submitted
  })

  return (
    <div className="progress">{progress}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You may find some inspiration in [this blog](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/88d2789e408a).

Comment: This blog just points towards statistics

Comment: you are right, the [link to the blog is this one](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a)

Comment: That link is very helpful, I will try that out, thank you.